# admin-on-rest Don't show list/add views when one entry exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, admin-on-rest

Given that a user can add only one entry of one ''. The user(by design) cannot add more than one entry of e.g Business ''.

The requirement here is that once a user can have only one entry '1-1' (1 user has 1 Business) relation, the loggedin user should NOT see the 'list' and the 'add' view and in case of reaching the url (e.g '/businesses') to automatically redirect to the edit view(e.g '/businesses/edit/xxx').

The user can only see the '/businesses' and '/businesses/add' when he has no 'business' added yet.

The problem here is that the '' is the one that automatically makes the magic to fetch the list of the businesses and display them. This doesn't prevent your from navigating to the '/businesses' url once these two operations are separate.

Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

This will require more than just Client side manipulation I feel.

What you need is a custom Menu. You can pass a custom menu as a prop to admin

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Admin.html#menu

Then you have 2 options.

1) Wrap the menu component inside a referenceField and force a rerender of the component when a record is received from your API (the record can be null as well) depending on this you can display the menu accordingly.

However, I am pretty sure that wrapping Menu in ReferenceField will cause some rendering problem. You will have to provide a default case etc.

2) I feel that a simpler solution is possible especially if you have control of your API. Just send back a user status along side your authentication data at log in time. You can then edit your auth client to store the status field in localStorage. You can then access that stored user status and show the menu accordingly.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. I'm afraid that the first option will trigger some optimization issues. About the second one, was one of the option that  I initial thought about, but the problem is that you need somehow make 'blacklist' the urls that you don't want to show the user. Do you have something in your mind?

Comment: What you are thinking about are Permissions. AOR has a auth management feature that let's you control what view to display to user based on their permissions.

https://marmelab.com/admin-on-rest/Authorization.html